# How to customise the Input fields when using react-jsonschema-form

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema, react-forms, react-jsonschema-forms, angular6-json-schema-form

I want to add html like  inside the label element in the input fields when using react-jsonschema-form.
Also remove the helper text from below the input field.
Ex:
[image]
Or is there a way to add tooltip next to label for inputfields?

I have tried https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/docs/advanced-customization/custom-templates/#descriptionfieldtemplate & https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/docs/advanced-customization/custom-widgets-fields but no luck with inputfields.

Has anyone encountered this?